# Add placeholder/help text to Views exposed filter?

Tags: views

Title pretty much says it all. I am looking for a way to add placeholder/help text to a Views exposed filter. This would be text that appears in the filter (in this case, search field) before the user enters a value, and then disappears when the filed is clicked or when text is entered into it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with preprocess functions.  Here's a tutorial on doing this for the [default search box](http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/04/magically-disappearing-default-search-text); you can do views exposed filters in a similar way.

You may also be able to use the [Compact Forms](http://drupal.org/project/compact_forms) module to do this, though I don't know if it is compatible with Views exposed filters.

Also, there's a module for showing helper text below a field: [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)

To set it up, simply enable the module and then navigate to your view edit page.

- Under **Exposed Form**, click **Basic** next to *Exposed form style* and change it to *Better Exposed Filters*.
- Click on **Settings**.
- Scroll to the bottom and click on **Exposed Filter Settings**.
- Click on **Advanced filter options** and you will see the input text in there, then adjust as necessary.

However, this module will not automatically hide the text upon input.

Comment: I already have Better Exposed Filters installed, but I don't see this option in my setting anywhere. The only thing close to it that I see is a Description area under Better Exposed Filter's settings. This just places helper text below the field, though. Do you happen to know where this option is?

Comment: Sorry, Better Exposed Filters doesn't have that option.  I misread your question; see my update above.

Comment: Haven't gotten a chance to try it out yet as I've been busy on other projects, but this seems like the correct way to go about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I've been searching for that and could add placeholder with that way:

1. Open your theme's template.php file (if not exist create one).
2. Add the code below to your template.php file:

(Read the notes below the code.)

```
function mmsearchresults_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == "views_exposed_form"){
    dsm($form); // print $form array on the top of the page
    if (isset($form['title'])) {
            $form['title']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => array(t('Gemeente...')));
    }
  }
}
```

Note 1: If the form_alter function is already exist, do not add it again, just copy and paste the `if($form_id=...)` part.

Note 2: Change the 'title' whatever element you want to add placeholder.

Note 3: If you want not to display label, you could do this by css (display: none) or by adding `unset($form['title']['#title']);` inside of the code above.

Comment: Keep in mind, "views_exposed_form" as ID, will target ALL views exposed forms.
Additionally, add an extra validation inside the condition. For example:
`if ($form['#id'] == "the-specific-form-id") {
   //The form specific modifications here..
}`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue about putting a placeholder on a exposed filter input, that's why I use jQuery code on a "diplay:none;" bloc.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(function($){
        var elm = $("#id-of-the-input");
        elm.val(elm.attr('name'));
        elm.focus(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if(elm.val() == elm.attr('name')){
                elm.val('');
            }
        });
        elm.focusout(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if(elm.val() == ""){
                elm.val(elm.attr('name'));
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a more specific approach with hook_form_FORM_ID_alter:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for views_exposed_form().
*/
function hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['form_name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Placeholder text here');
}
```